# This is regarding Python Exponentiation

Tags: python, exponentiation

```
print (2**3**2)
```

Answer is 512.
Why 512 is answer not 64? Because ((2^3)^2) = 64
I want to know the inside math operation of  print (2** 3**2)

Answer (score 1):

The order of operations for exponentiation is right-to-left, not-left-to right.  So:

```
2**3**2
```

is interpretted as:

```
2**(3**2) = 2**(9) = 512
```